# use foreach for a property in C#

Tags: c#

I define a property like this :

```
public IMAGE_DOS_HEADER  ImageDosHeader 
        {

            get
            {
                return imageDosHeader; 
            }
        }
```

where IMAGE_DOS_HEADER is a struct like this

```
public struct IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
        {      // DOS .EXE header
            public UInt16 e_magic;              // Magic number
            public UInt16 e_cblp;               // Bytes on last page of file
            public UInt16 e_cp;                 // Pages in file
            public UInt16 e_crlc;               // Relocations
            public UInt16 e_cparhdr;            // Size of header in paragraphs
            public UInt16 e_minalloc;           // Minimum extra paragraphs needed
         }
```

and finally I want use this property in main program using foreach like this

```
foreach (var DosHeader in reader.ImageDosHeader)
       {
           listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add(DosHeader.ToString("X"));
           i++;
       }
```

but an compile error occured:
" Error 1   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'PEfileReader.PeHeaderReader.IMAGE_DOS_HEADER' because 'PEfileReader.PeHeaderReader.IMAGE_DOS_HEADER' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator"

anybody can help me?

Comment: What is there to enumerate in a struct? It looks like there's only one, not an array of them

Comment: What about creating Generic List List<ImageDosHeader> idh = new List<ImageDosHeader>();. Then you may add elements like idh.Add(new ImageDoesHeader{ e_magic = 1, e_cblp = 2, e_cp = 3, e_crlc = 4, e_cparhdr = 5, e_minalloc = 6 });. Now you can iterate over collection with foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

To get fields of a struct you should use reflection

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER header = new IMAGE_DOS_HEADER() { e_cblp = 1, e_cp = 2, e_cparhdr = 3, e_crlc = 4, e_magic = 5, e_minalloc = 6 };

var fieldsAndValues = 
        typeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER)
        .GetFields()
        .Select(f=>new {
            Name= f.Name,  //<== Name of the field
            Value = f.GetValue(header) //<==Value of the field
        })
        .ToList();
```

Then you can insert the values to a listview

```
foreach (var item in fieldsAndValues)
{
    listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add(item.Value);
}
```

Comment: I'm starting to feel that we all made the wrong assumptions; the OP doesn't seem to be trying to enumerate the fields after all?

Comment: thank you thats a good answer but still I cant put the items in listview

Comment: @user1510265 that you can't put these name/value pairs to a listview is not related with your question. I have no idea what you use (ASP.Net, Winforms, WPF etc) and how you use.

Comment: dear friend I write these codes in tow column listview but only listview only show me value in column2 and column1 is emptly

Comment: foreach (var itm in fieldsAndValues)
           {
               ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();
               Int32 intTmp= Int32.Parse( itm.Value.ToString());
               item1.SubItems.Add(intTmp.ToString("X"));
               item1.SubItems.Add(itm.Name);
               listView3.Items.Add(item1);
                       
           }

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing `IEnumerable` with your struct IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your IMAGE_DOS_HEADER struct to the following:

```
 public struct IMAGE_DOS_HEADER : IEnumerable<UInt16>
    {      // DOS .EXE header
        public UInt16 e_magic;              // Magic number
        public UInt16 e_cblp;               // Bytes on last page of file
        public UInt16 e_cp;                 // Pages in file
        public UInt16 e_crlc;               // Relocations
        public UInt16 e_cparhdr;            // Size of header in paragraphs
        public UInt16 e_minalloc;           // Minimum extra paragraphs needed


        public IEnumerator<UInt16> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator<UInt16>)(new[] {e_magic, e_cblp, e_cp, e_crlc, e_cparhdr, e_minalloc}.GetEnumerator());
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new[] { e_magic, e_cblp, e_cp, e_crlc, e_cparhdr, e_minalloc }.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```